# Por que se elimina el texto ingresado o es remplazado

Tags: c

Tengo una función para limitar los caracteres pero cuando ingreso correctamente el primer valor y el segundo valor sobre paso el limite y me pide que ingrese de nuevo eh ingreso correctamente.

[image: no aparece lo ingresado del primer jugador]

```
void * limitar (char *PAL){
    int c=0;
    //PAL = malloc((sizeof(char) *LONGITUD)+1); cuando coloco el malloc me aparecen caracteres
    do{
        if(c>0){
            printf(" error:OUT OF RANGE \n Intentalo de nuevo: ");
        }
        gets(PAL);
        printf("%d %d",(strlen(PAL)),LONGITUD);
        c++;
    }while(strlen(PAL)>LONGITUD);
    return(PAL);
}
```

Se muy bien que puede usar `fgets` y listo pero quiero tener mas opciones.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "Funciones.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char nombre[LONGITUD],nombre2[LONGITUD],*PPJ1,*PPJ2;
printf("Ingrese sus nombres\n\n Primer jugador : ");
limitar(nombre);
printf("%s",nombre);
printf("Segundo jugador: ");
limitar(nombre2);
printf("\nPerfecto %s y %s\nElijan sus pokemons primero %s\n",nombre,nombre2,nombre);
PPJ1 = menu_poke(nombre);
printf("%s",PPJ1);
free(PPJ1);
printf("\n Bien es tu turno %s\n",nombre2);
PPJ2 = menu_poke(nombre2);
printf("\n         GO COMIENZEN \n");
combate(nombre);  
return 0;
```

}

```
#include <stdio.h>
//incluye libreria entrada estandar
//esta strlen()
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Consonante
#define CANT_BYTES 132
#define LONGITUD   20
#define TAM_LISTA 3

void * limitar (char *PAL);
void * menu_poke(char * nombre);
void combate(char * nombre);
```

aqui tengo el header donde creo los prototipos de las funciones

Comment: Por favor, pon un ejemplo que incluya la llamada a `limitar` y la declaración e inicialización de `PAL`

Comment: Debajo de las etiquetas de la pregunta tienes "Compartir Editar Seguir Reportar". Si pulsas Editar, te deja editar la pregunta.

Comment: añadi main donde llamo a esa funcion limitar

Comment: @SuperG280 alli te dejo todo mi codigo

Comment: cuando no supere el limite todo muestra correctamente pero si uno de ellos supera el limite oo muestra lo ingresado

Comment: Ya pude ver bien la imagen. No te parece coincidencia que los últimos caracteres de tu nombre extra largo sean los que reemplazan a tu primer nombre? Tus 2 nombres están uno al lado del otro en la memoria, y si te pasas escribiendo uno vas a sobreescribir el otro.

Comment: cuando no supere el limite todo muestra correctamente pero si uno de ellos supera el limite oo muestra lo ingresado

Comment: "*Se muy bien que puede usar `fgets` y listo pero quiero tener mas opciones.*". Opciones de que? Con `fgets` limitas la cantidad de caracteres que lees del stream, eliminando tu problema con el overflow. Si tienes mas opciones, pero estas tomando la opcion incorrecta.

Comment: ok pero que otras opciones puedo tomar, y como resuelvo ese problema con el overflow

Comment: @Jean Para que quieres mas opciones que `fgets`? Si funciona, y lo hace bien, no hace falta cambiarlo, menos por algo tan propenso a bugs como `gets` o `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que estás pisando memoria de otras variables.

La memoria de tu programa se estructura de la siguiente manera:

```
 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ...
|                        nombre2                         |     nombre       |
```

Así, tu primero introduces `hola` en `nombre`:

```
 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ...
|                        nombre2                         |     nombre       |
                                                           h  o  l  a \0
```

Y después introduces la secuencia `123456789s123456789s4`, dejando la memoria tal que:

```
 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ...
|                        nombre2                         |     nombre       |
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  s  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  s  4 \0  a \0
```

Como ves, el contenido de `nombre` se ha visto modificado y ahora es `s4\0a\0`.

Después vuelves a modificar `nombre2`:

```
 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ...
|                        nombre2                         |     nombre       |
  h  o  l  a \0  6  7  8  9  s  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  s  4 \0  a \0
```

El caracter `\0` marca el final de las cadenas en C, luego al imprimir el contenido de la memoria, `nombre2` muestra `hola` mientras que `nombre` mostrará `s4`.

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar `fgets` en vez de `gets` y limpiar el buffer de entrada

```
int error;
do 
{
    fgets(PAL, LONGITUD, stdin);

    error = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { error = 1; }

    if (error != 0)
    {
       puts("OUT OF RANGE\n");
    }
} while (error);

// fgets puede dejar el salto de línea en la cadena, lo eliminamos
PAL[strcspn(PAL, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Funciona de la siguiente manera:

`fgets` recupera como mucho los primeros `LONGITUD` caracteres. Seguidamente entra en juego la lógica para vaciar el buffer. Si hay más caracteres pendientes, `error` se pondrá a 1 y entonces podrás mostrar un bonito mensaje de error.

Comment: Tu respuesta tiene un pequeño error, si el usuario introduce menos de `LONGITUD` caracteres el buffer se queda vació, obligando al usuario a «pulsar enter» una vez más. Si el usuario no sabe que ocurre continuara escribiendo y se *mostrar un bonito mensaje de error*.

Comment: @AriadnaCortéz te equivocas o no te estoy entendiendo bien. El programa funciona correctamente [enlace](https://wandbox.org/permlink/a7pMKGo67u3syZHd)

Comment: `getchar` devuelve el siguiente carácter en el *buffer de entrada*, si el buffer esta vació se queda a la espera de nuevos caracteres. Para notarlo tienes que compilar y ejecutar en local, usando el teclado como entrada de datos. Prueba a teclear ***hola** (enter)*; Noté que se usa la opción **-std=gnu++2b**, si nuevos cambios en **C++20** son la razón de las diferencias, me disculpo, y te pido perdón por los inconvenientes.

Answer (score 0):

Basada en la respuesta de [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/460071/230848).

---

Gracias a que `fgets` retiene el carácter de *nueva línea* podemos usar esto
para determinar si el usuario excedió el limite de caracteres que tenia permitido
 ingresar. Con la ayuda de `strrchr` podemos ubicar el `\n` dentro del arreglo y
reemplazarlo por `\0`, pero si el carácter de nueva línea no esta presente, `strrchr`
retornará `NULL` y podremos comenzar a limpiar el buffer de manera segura.

**Aquí el codigo:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LONGITUD 10

char *limitar(char *destino, size_t longitud)
{
    char *nl = NULL;
    int error;
    
    do
    {
        fgets(destino, longitud, stdin);
        
        error = 0;
        
        if ((nl = strrchr(destino, '\n')) == NULL)
        {
            int c;
            
            while (((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF)) { error = 1; }
            
            if (error != 0)
            {
                puts("¡Demasiado largo!\nIntenta otra vez.\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            *nl = '\0';
        }
    } while (error);
    
    return (destino);
}

int main()
{
    char PAL[LONGITUD] = {'\n'};
    
    puts("¿Cuál es tu nombre? ");
    limitar(PAL, LONGITUD);
    
    printf("Gracias «%s».\n", PAL);
    
    return 0;
}
```

---

La línea

```c
char PAL[LONGITUD] = {'\n'};
```

tiene un propósito muy importante, si el usuario introduce un `EOF` de forma manual, el bloque

```c
if ((nl = strrchr(PAL, '\n')) == NULL)
{
…
}
else
{
…
}
```

se ejecuta de igual modo, garantizando así que `getchar` no se quede a la espera de nuevos caracteres.

**Y el resultado:**

- Cuando el usuario excede la longitud maxima.

```
SALIDA:
¿Cuál es tu nombre? 
Ariadna Cortéz
¡Demasiado largo!
Intenta otra vez.

Ariadna C.
¡Demasiado largo!
Intenta otra vez.

Ariadna
Gracias «Ariadna».
```

- Cuando el usuario introduce un `EOF` o no introduce nada.

```
SALIDA:
¿Cuál es tu nombre? 
Gracias «».
```